# Python - Split file into multiple files for each occurence of a specific string

Tags: python

I have a single file with multiple stored procedures in it like below.

```
--
-- Name: abc(character varying); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: schema_name; Owner: -
--
CREATE FUNCTION schema_name.abc(schema_name character varying) RETURNS opaque
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS '54:-1', $$
    
DECLARE
 a  INT:= 0;
 b  INT:= 0;

BEGIN 
        
 
 END;

$$;


--
-- Name: bcd(); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: schema_name; Owner: -
--

CREATE FUNCTION schema_name.bcd() RETURNS opaque
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS '-1', $$         

DECLARE
 a  INT:= 0;
 b  INT:= 0;

BEGIN 
    
 
 END;
    $$;


--
-- Name: cde(); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: schema_name; Owner: -
--

CREATE FUNCTION schema_name.cde() RETURNS opaque
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS '-1', $$         

DECLARE
 a  INT:= 0;
 b  INT:= 0;

BEGIN 
    

 
 END;
    $$;
```

I need to separate it into each single procedure file that starts with

```
--
-- Name:
```

Also the individual files should be named after the schema name. In this case, the file names should be abc.sql, bcd.sql, cde.sql..

So far I tried this

```
token = 'CREATE FUNCTION'
chunks = []
current_chunk = []

for line in open('procedures.txt'):
   if line.startswith(token) and current_chunk: 
      chunks.append(current_chunk[:])
      current_chunk = []
   current_chunk.append(line)
   print (current_chunk)

chunks.append(current_chunk)
```

Comment: You are expected to solve the problem first.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would use a basic file open read into the memory and then line by line parse the text to look for start and stop points. Once the pieces are split into the appropriate sizes, then you can look for the schema text. Then it's simply a matter of saving it with the schema name you just found.

Comment: You have edited your question and said what your code is, that is fine, but you should also describe the problem. The code missbehaves? You get an error? You need to know how to write files using python? You do not know how to get the filename from the create function line? As is, your question is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os

path = r"D:\test"

token = '-- Name: '
chunks = {}
current_chunk = []


with open (os.path.join(path, "test.txt"), "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines()

for line in data:
    if line.startswith(token):
        start = line.find("token")+len(token)
        end = line.find("(")
        schema_name = line[start:end].strip()
        
        current_chunk = []
        current_chunk.append(line)
        chunks[schema_name] = current_chunk
    else:
        current_chunk.append(line)

print (chunks)

for name, storage in chunks.items():
    print(name)
    with open(os.path.join(path, name + '.sql'), 'w') as file:
        file.write(" ".join(storage))
        file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas..This is exactly what I needed

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding!